# Why does L'Hopital not apply to $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{5x+3}{\sqrt{4x^2-x+7}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am given the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{5x+3}{\sqrt{4x^2-x+7}}$$

By simply dividing all factors by $x$, one can wind up with the result $\frac{5}{2}$. However, this is also a limit of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, thus one should be able to apply L'Hopital:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{5}{\frac{8x-1}{2\sqrt{4x^2-x+7}}} = 0$$

seeing as we are dividing a constant number by something infinitely large. Where is the mistake in my logic here?

EDIT: Found the mistake after writing this question, will update post with correct answer if this is not already sufficiently answered when I'm finished calculating.

Comment: Your "infinitely large number" is not actually infinitely large, remember that $a/(b/c) = $ac/b$.

Comment: Think about $\sqrt{x^2-x}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Why not post your update as an answer! It is perfectly appropriate to do so, and having posted both the question and the corrected update in the form of an answer is a great learning experience. You're perfectly entitled to accept your own answer, as well, particularly if you've discovered the problem and correct solution largely on your own!

Comment: The way you have applied the L'Hospital is OK. You get $5$ in numerator and you get another fraction in denominator. Now you need to understand very clearly that this denominator thing itself tends to $2$ as $x \to \infty$ so that the whole stuff tends to $5/2$ as expected. You have made the mistake of thinking that the denominator is tending to $\infty$ and numerator being $5$ the whole thing tends to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application of L'Hospital's on radical  seems to be never ending.

$$\text{As }\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{5x+3}{\sqrt{4x^2-x+7}}=\sqrt{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(5x+3)^2}{4x^2-x+7}},$$

Now applying L'Hospital's
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(5x+3)^2}{4x^2-x+7}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2(5x+3)\cdot5}{8x-1}$$ which is again of the form $\displaystyle\frac\infty\infty$

So applying L'Hospital's again, $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{10(5x+3)}{8x-1}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{10\cdot5}8=\frac{25}4$$

Comment: Don't forget the square root at the end to finish the solution :)

Comment: @Clayton, I left it to the OP

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing a constant by something which tends to 2...

Answer (score -1):

my answer:

$\lim_{n\to -\infty} \frac{5x}{\sqrt{4x^2-x+7}}=-\frac{5}{2}$

$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{5x}{\sqrt{4x^2-x+7}}=\frac{5}{2}$

Comment: This answer is not very instructive, as it provides **nothing** in the way of an explanation, and does not address the questions of the OP.

Comment: @amWhy: This limit is too known, do not need to be displayed one way ambiguous